# yadcf range_date filter always returns empty value

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I have this datatable and i'm trying to use [YADCF](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) to filter my results. The table works fine and the filter UI loads perfectlly, but when i select a date, it filters all results and even when i **delete** the selection, the 'filter' stays applied until i refresh the page. This bug applies to all yadcf filters, not only range_date.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var active = $('#active').DataTable( {
        global: false,
        "dom": 'f<"toolbar">rtilp',
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "processing_active.php"
        },

        "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]]',[ 2, "asc" ],[ 10, "desc" ]],
        "deferRender": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[55, 155, 250, -1], [55, 155, 250, 'All']],
        "columns": [
        {
            "class":          "details-control",
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": "",
            "visible":        false
        },
        { "data": "loadNumber","width": "8em"},
        { "data": "driverName","width": "10em"},
        { "data": "truckNum","width": "5em"},
        { "data": "puDate","width": "9em"},
        { "data": "puCity", "width": "10em"  },
        { "data": "puState", "width": "1em" },
        { "data": "regStatus"},
        { "data": "deCity", "width": "10em" }, 
        { "data": "deState", "width": "1em"}, 
        { "data": "deDate","width": "9em"},
        { "data": "loadRate","width": "7em"},
        { "data": "confNumber", "width" : "9em"},
        { "data": "dispatcherName", "width": "10em"},
        { "data": "smallStatus"}
        ]
    });
     $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#active').dataTable().yadcf([

                    {
                    column_number: 4,
                    filter_type: "range_date",
                    }
        ]);

    });
```

Comment: Did you wrote the filtering logic on your server side? because when using datatables with server side processing all your filtering logic is done on the server too... you need to parse the `columns[0][search][value]` / `columns[1][search][value]`  / etc and return only relevant value back to the client

Comment: Do you mean i should edit `server_processing.php` or `ssp.class.php`, using the example from your website ? If so, how specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the filtering logic on your server side, because when using datatables with server side processing all your filtering logic is done on the server too, you need to parse the `columns[0][search][value]` / `columns[1][search][value]` / etc and return only relevant rows back to the client,

You can use the github to try and find some relevant example using yadcf and php, here a possibly [search query on github](https://github.com/search?l=php&q=yadcf&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

p.s you really should use the following syntax to init yadcf, in the first ready block of your code just after constructing datatables, call the following code

```
yadcf.init(active,.....
```

Comment: filter of type `range_date` sends `-yadcf_delim-` as a  value. like `columns[3][search][value]:-yadcf_delim-` .

Comment: @tchelidze , it send that when you reset the date filter, see yourself on showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

Comment: Thanks, in my case, selecting date on dropdown calendar does not send request to server at all. Editing another column filter sends a request but for `column[3]` search value is blank, e.i `-yadcf_delim-`

Comment: then you will have to post an new q' with a sample jsbin/etc that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead for your `yadcf`:

```
yadcf.init(active, [{
    column_number:       4,
    column_data_type:    'text',
    filter_type:         'range_date'
}]);
```